# I cant edit cover picture and profile picture using firebase storage. What's wrong in my program?

Tags: java, android, firebase, storage

I added user profile page in my project which is ProfileFragment.java and it's layout file is fragment_profile.xml. I want to update user information like name,description, profile pic and cover page. My program does not have error, name and description update successfully but cover and profile pictures does not update? What is wrong in my code?

This is my ProfileFragment.java

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    //Log Statment
    private static final String TAG = "ProfileFragment";

    //firebase auth
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    //firabase storage
    StorageReference storageReference;
    //profil resminin ve kapak resminin nerede depolanacağının yolu
    String storagePath = "Users_Profile_Cover_Imgs/";

    //layout views
    ImageView avatar, coverPhoto;
    TextView nameTxt, emailTxt, descTxt;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    //Progress Dialog
    ProgressDialog pd;

    //permissions
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUESTED_CODE = 100;
    private static final int STORAGE_REQUESTED_CODE = 200;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE = 300;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE = 400;

    //izinler için gerekli arrayler
    String cameraPermissions[];
    String storagePermissions[];

    //seçilen resmin uri adresi
    Uri image_uri;

    //profil fotografı yoksa kapak fotografımı kontrol et
    String profileORCoverPhoto;



    public ProfileFragment() {
        //boş public constructor gerekli
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

        //init firebase
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");

        //init layout views

        avatar = view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        coverPhoto = view.findViewById(R.id.coverPhoto);
        nameTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
        emailTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.emailTxt);
        descTxt = view.findViewById(R.id.descTxt);
        fab = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        //izin arrayleri
        cameraPermissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        storagePermissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};



        /* giriş yapan kullanıcıların bilgilerini email yada uid kullanarak çekmek zorundayız
        Kullanıcı detaylarını email adreslerini kullanarak çekicez
        orderbyChild query kullanarak giriş yapılan email ile email key ini eşleştirerek kullanıcı detaylarına ulaşılıyor
         */
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(user.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //gerekli veriler gelene kadar kontrol et
                for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    //verileri almak için
                    String name = ""+ ds.child("name").getValue();
                    String email = ""+ ds.child("email").getValue();
                    String desc = ""+ ds.child("desc").getValue();
                    String image = ""+ ds.child("image").getValue();
                    String cover = ""+ ds.child("cover").getValue();



                    //set data
                    nameTxt.setText(name);
                    emailTxt.setText(email);
                    descTxt.setText(desc);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: \nName: "+name+" email: "+ email);


                    try {
                        // resim alınırsa ayarla
                        Picasso.get().load(image).into(avatar);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        // resim alınırken herangi bir sıkıntı varsa varsayılan olarak ayarla
                        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.add_photo_foreground).into(avatar);
                    }

                    try {
                        // kapak resimi alınırsa ayarla
                        Picasso.get().load(cover).into(coverPhoto);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        // kapak resmi alınırken herangi bir sıkıntı varsa varsayılan olarak ayarla
                        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.default_cover_photo).into(coverPhoto);
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: Data is empty");

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: "+error);
            }
        });

        //fab button onClick özelliği ekleme
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //edit profile dialog göster
                showEditProfileDialog();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }


    private void requestStoragePermission(){
        //runtime depolama izinleri isteme
        requestPermissions(storagePermissions, STORAGE_REQUESTED_CODE);
    }
    private void requestCameraPermission(){
        //runtime depolama izinleri isteme
        requestPermissions(cameraPermissions, CAMERA_REQUESTED_CODE);
    }

    private boolean checkStoragePermission(){
        //depolama izinlerini kontrol et, etkinse true, değilse false döndür
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        return  result;
    }
    private boolean checkCameraPermission(){
        //depolama izinlerini kontrol et, etkinse true, değilse false döndür
        boolean result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        boolean result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        return  result && result1;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        //Bu yöntem, kullanıcı izin isteği iletişim kutusundan izin ver veya reddet düğmesine bastığında çağrılır
        //burada izin durumlarını ele alınır(izin verildi ve reddedildi)
        switch (requestCode){
            case CAMERA_REQUESTED_CODE: {
                //camera seçildiğinde önce izin alınmış mı diye kontrol eder
                if (grantResults.length > 0 ){
                    boolean cameraAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeStorageAccepted  = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if(cameraAccepted && writeStorageAccepted){
                        //izinler etkinleştirildi
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }
                    else{
                        //izinler reddedildi
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enable camera && storage permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
            //galeri seçildiğinde önce izin alınmış mı diye kontrol eder
            case STORAGE_REQUESTED_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 ){
                    boolean cameraAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean writeStorageAccepted  = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    if(writeStorageAccepted){
                        //izinler etkinleştirildi
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }
                    else{
                        //izinler reddedildi
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please enable storage permission",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        //bu metot camera veya galeri den fotograf seçildikten sonra çağırılıyor
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE){
                //resim geleriden seçildi, resmin uri'sini al
                image_uri = data.getData();

                uploadProfileCoverPhoto(image_uri);
            }
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
                //resim cameradan seçildi, resmin uri'sini al

                uploadProfileCoverPhoto(image_uri);

            }


        }


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }



    //Editprofile dialog
    private void showEditProfileDialog() {
        // Profil resmi düzenle, kapak fotografı gösterme, isim düzenleme, açıklama düzenleme
        //Seçenekleri dialogta gösterme
        String options[] = {"Edit Profile Picture", "Edit Cover Photo", "Edit Name", "Edit Description"};

        //alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //başlık
        builder.setTitle("Choose Action");
        //dialog itemlerini ayarlama
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //dialog itemlere onClick özelliği ekleme
                if (which == 0){
                    //profil düzenleme tıklandı
                    pd.setMessage("Updating Profile Picture");

                    //profil foto mu yoksa kapak foto mu konrol için
                    profileORCoverPhoto = "image"; // profil resmini değiştirirken aynı değerlerin atandığından emin ol

                    showImagePicDialog();

                }
                else if (which == 1){
                    //kapak düzenleme tıklandı
                    pd.setMessage("Updating Cover Picture");

                    //profil foto mu yoksa kapak foto mu konrol için
                    profileORCoverPhoto = "cover"; //kapak resmini değiştirirken aynı değerlerin atandığından emin ol

                    showImagePicDialog();
                }
                else if (which == 2){
                    //isim duzenleme tıklandı
                    pd.setMessage("Updating Name");

                    //veritabanında "name" güncellenmesi için motodun çağırılması
                    showNameDescUpdateDialog("name");

                }
                else if (which == 3){
                    //açıklama düzenleme tıklandı
                    pd.setMessage("Updating Description");

                    showNameDescUpdateDialog("desc");


                }

            }
        });
        //dialog oluşturme ve gösterme
        builder.create().show();
    }


    private void showNameDescUpdateDialog(final String key) {
        //key parametresi "name" ve "desc" değerlerini alıyor

        //custom dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Update "+key); //Update name or Update description..

        //Dialog layoutunu ayarla
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
        //editText ekleme
        final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
        editText.setHint("Enter "+ key);
        linearLayout.addView(editText);

        builder.setView(linearLayout);

        //dialog'a update button ekle
        builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //input text from edit text
                String value = editText.getText().toString().trim();
                //kullanıcının bir şeyler girip girmediğini onayla
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value)){
                    pd.show();
                    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                    result.put(key, value);
                    databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(result)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    //güncellendi, dismiss progress
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Updated...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            //error mesajı al ve göster, dismiss progress
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Enter "+key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        //dialog'a cancel button ekle
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        //dialog'u oluştur ve göster
        builder.create().show();
    }


    private void showImagePicDialog() {
        //profil resmini cameradan ya da galeriden seçme seçenekleri ekleme
        String options[] = {"Camera", "Gallery"};

        //alert dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //başlık
        builder.setTitle("Pick Image From");
        //dialog itemlerini ayarlama
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //dialog itemlere onClick özelliği ekleme
                if (which == 0){
                    //camera tıklandı
                    // pd.setMessage("Updating Profile Picture");
                    //showImagePicDialog();
                    if (!checkCameraPermission()){
                        requestCameraPermission();
                    }
                    else{
                        pickFromCamera();
                    }
                }
                else if (which == 1){
                    //galeir tıklandı
                    //pd.setMessage("Updating Cover Picture");
                    if(!checkStoragePermission()){
                        requestStoragePermission();
                    }
                    else {
                        pickFromGallery();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //dialog oluşturme ve gösterme
        builder.create().show();

    }


    private void uploadProfileCoverPhoto(final Uri uri) {
        //Show progress dialog
        pd.show();

        //iki ayrı fonksiyon yerine profil resmi ve kapak resmi aynı fonksiyonda

        //firabase storage'da depolanan resmin yolu ve adı
        String filePathAndName = storagePath+ ""+ profileORCoverPhoto + "_"+ user.getUid();

        StorageReference storageReference2nd = storageReference.child(filePathAndName);
        storageReference2nd.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //resim depoya yüklendi, şimdi url'sini al ve kullanıcı veritabanında sakla
                        Task<Uri> uriTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!uriTask.isSuccessful());
                        Uri downloadUri = uriTask.getResult();

                        //resmin yüklenip yüklenmediğini ve url'nin alındığını kontrol edin
                        if (uriTask.isSuccessful()){
                            //resim yüklendi
                            //kullanıcı veritabanına url'i ekle/güncelle
                            HashMap<String, Object> results = new HashMap<>();

                            //ilk parametre profileOrCoverPhote image veya cover değerlerine sahip
                            //ikinci parametre firebase storage'da depolanan resmin url
                            results.put(profileORCoverPhoto, downloadUri.toString());

                            databaseReference.child(user.getUid()).updateChildren(results)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                            pd.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image Updated...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error Updating Image...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });

                        }
                        else {
                            //error
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Some error occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                         //bazı errorlar var, errorları al ve error mesajı göster, dissmis dialog
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 }
        });

    }

    private void pickFromCamera() {
        //cihaz kamerasından görüntü alma
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "Temp Pic");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Temp Description");

        //resim uri'si
        image_uri = getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        //camera başlatılması
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);


    }

    private void pickFromGallery() {
        //galeriden resim seçme
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);

    }


}
```

My AndroidManifes.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gamze.pawsbook">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My build.gradle(module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gamze.pawsbook"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // add the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'

    //Firebase authentication library
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'

    //google sign in library
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'

    //Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'

    //Firebase Storage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'


    //Picasso library (resimleri eklemek için)
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'


}
```

Comment: Can you answer my question please???? @NikhilSharma

Comment: I try to provide a working code, which I was using to put image in Firbase, I might look into your code as well but that will be tomorrow, as it's getting late and I need to sleep :D

Comment: Thanks. i am waiting for you :D @NikhilSharma

Comment: have you tried my suggestion in answer ?

Comment: Yes i tryed. Your answer is also good way but my mistake was different. When i add  storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();  in onCreateView class my problem fixed. But still thank you for your help..

Comment: glad to find you fixed it, I was having nightmare last night about this :D ...

Comment: Really:D  Sorry for causing this ..:D

Comment: I think you can help me if I have another problem. @NikhilSharma

Comment: always on toes for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest try to save Bitmap after converting it to `ByteArrayOutputStream` not `URI`.

You can get user selected Bitmap as follows -

```
....
Bitmap newImage;                 //make it a global variable
.....

    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
                switch (requestCode) {
                    case 0:                            //Image from Camera
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                            newImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                            userImage.setImageBitmap(newImage);
                            newImageSet = true;
                        }
    
                        break;
                    case 1:                           //Image from gallery/user device
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                            if (selectedImage != null) {
                                Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                                if (cursor != null) {
                                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                                    newImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                                    userImage.setImageBitmap(newImage);
                                    cursor.close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

After getting new image bitmp this is how you can put Bitmap in Firstore.

```
public void saveImageToFirbase(){

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            newImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, byteArrayOutputStream);
            StorageReference imgReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("User Profile Image")   
                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + ".jpeg");
                    //adjust imgReference according to your database structure 

            imgReference.putBytes(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            getDownloadUrl(imgReference);
                            
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", e.getCause());
                        }
                    });
}
```

Here `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40` integer value will be the level of compression.

Method getgetDownloadUrl() -

```
private void getDownloadUrl(StorageReference storageReference) {
    storageReference.getDownloadUrl()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    setUserProfileUrl(uri);
                }
            });
}
```

And at least you can update user's Profile and set ImageUrl -

```
private void setUserProfileUrl(Uri userProfileUrl) {
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    UserProfileChangeRequest userProfileChangeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            .setPhotoUri(userProfileUrl).build();
    firebaseUser.updateProfile(userProfileChangeRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    //some more update in your view
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", e.getCause());
                }
            });
}
```

Happy Coding !